# Extracting string between keywords and assigning it to a variable

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to extract strings/lines between specific keywords from a log file and then assign it to a variable or a counter. For eg: I have a log file which is something like:

```
This is line 1 of the log file
line 2 of the log file
DEF this is something in line 3
this is a 123 456
34
cat dog rainfall 
some relevant information
ABC
DEF something in this line
this is a 123 678
ABC
```

Here the start keyword is "DEF" and the end keyword is "ABC". And I want to extract the line that has keyword "this is" from between these keywords. Output should be like:

Iteration 1 = [123, 456]
Iteration 2 = [123, 678]

My code so far..

```
import os
import re

def GetTheSubString(logfile):
    with open(logfile) as p:
        for result in re.findall('DEF(.*?)ABC', p.read(), re.S):
            return (result)

substr = GetTheSubString("P3.log")
substr
```

This returns me only the first part of the string. I have another piece of code that already does the mapping of 123 and 456 but I am not sure how it will tie to this loop. Any suggestions will be helpful. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is right. The only thing you are doing wrong is, returning the first result itself. Although `re.findall('DEF(.*?)ABC', p.read(), re.S)` finds all the relevant content, you iterate over it, and when you hit `return` for the first time, you end up returning the first element only. Make the following change:

```
>>> import os
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> def GetTheSubString(logfile):
...     with open(logfile) as p:
...         return re.findall('DEF(.*?)ABC', p.read(), re.S)
... 
>>> substr = GetTheSubString("P3.log")
>>> print substr
[' this is something in line 3\nthis is a 123 456\n34\ncat dog rainfall \nsome relevant information\n', ' something in this line\nthis is a 123 678\n']
```

Now, you can apply whatever you want to the grabbed content.

However, if you want to do it in the function itself, I would do:

```
>>> import os
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> def GetTheSubString(logfile):
...     with open(logfile) as p:
...         return re.findall('DEF(?:.*?)this is a (\d+) (\d+)(?:.*?)ABC', p.read(), re.S)
... 
>>> substr = GetTheSubString("a")
>>> print substr
[('123', '456'), ('123', '678')]
```

Here, the regex will match everything between 'DEF' to 'this', the two numbers in 'this is a $num1 $num2' and everything from there up to 'ABC'. However, it will return only the numbers, as the outer capturing groups have been removed.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/opsOXwD8XNgplHq4)